# Howto create random default values in Active Record Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to create some models with random attributes, albeit within some limits. What is the proper way of doing this in the migrations and is there a better suited type than integer for numbers less than 1000? I'm thinking of sth like below:

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :things, :integer, :default => "a number between 5 and 12"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :things, :integer, :default => (5..12).to_a.sample
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, and ust to extend a little, is there a way to decrease the probability of the upper and lower limits? So to say, to prevent 5 and 12 occur that much?

Comment: And one more thing: Is there a way to pull strings from a table or sth else? I mean, I may make a table full of possible values (string or integer) and I would like these to be used randomly instead of a range.

Comment: @barerd You can query a table, even make it a little ugly one-liner. You have 'connection' property in migrations, so you can do whatever you want with the database.

Comment: Hi, I read the [http://api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) and saw functions like:  
      def up  
        execute "ALTER TABLE `pages_linked_pages` ADD UNIQUE `page_id_linked_page_id` (`page_id`,`linked_page_id`)"  
      end    

So do I need a function like:  
      def up  
        execute "SELECT * FROM RandomNumbers"  
      end    

there to put these values into a hash and randomize from there?

Comment: This won't do what you think. That's going to set a random number as the default for ALL things each time the migration is run. So in development all things might be 2 by default then in production all things might be 4, but they'd never vary within a system.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't really say if each row should have a independent value or not. This answer assumes "yes, each row should have independent random value".

To achieve this, the random value must be generated by the database instead of Rails/ruby. Database function can be used to achieve this.

The following works for Rails 5.2 on Postgreql. I haven't checked other things so YMMV.

Rails 5.2 accepts database function as `default` if a proc is provided:

```rb
class AddFooInBars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    add_column(:bars, :foo, :int,
      default: -> { "floor(random() * 1000 + 1)::int" }
    )
```